# Is it possible for Vuejs to properly accept javascript File objects array as a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The code for the prop in the child component is shown below. Everything is working correctly, but I get this warning and I know it isn't being validated correctly. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UxdW.png)

```
props: {
    files: Array
  }
```

Is it possible to properly validate File objects in Vuejs?

Comment: Can you share the complete program? Link a fiddle to your question.

Comment: I think you pasted wrong props here. The problem is with `item` prop. But here is `files` prop and its not Object, as said there. Please, update code due to problem.

Comment: @Asimple Well definitely a rookie mistake... I was looking at the wrong prop, I had item: Object and changed it to item: File and it worked as expected. Thank you!